# Division algebra = Field?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, division-algebras

Is a division algebra a field? If not, why does it differ?

It is an abelian group with multiplication and division. How not a field?

Answer (score 5):

A [division algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) does not need to be associative or commutative.

The [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) are not commutative but are associative.

The [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) are neither commutative nor associative.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. (I unchanged my question as a result)

Comment: Note that some authors restrict the term "algebra" to associative algebras.

Comment: Also note that sometimes fields are not assumed to be commutative, in which case they are the same as (associative) division algebras.

Answer (score 3):

A division algebra is "essentially" an algebra with a division operation.

An algebra is "essentially" a vector space with a multiplication operation.

Any field is an algebra over itself (i.e. take both the scalars and vectors to be elements of the field -- the same way that any field is a vector space over itself, and then notice that multiplication of "vectors" is immediate since elements of a field can be multiplied with each other). Since division is also defined for elements of a field, any field also happens to be a division algebra.

However, in the same way that not all vector spaces are fields, not all algebras are fields, and not all division algebras are fields. Fields are just a special case.